# Render alternate component in Visualforce for $Permission

Tags: visualforce

I am attempting to present an alternate message to a user if they do not have a particular Custom Permission assigned to them.

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!$Permission.Allow_This}">
        <apex:outputText>Click this button to do something</apex:outputText>
        <apex:commandButton value="Click Me!" action="{!clickButton}" />
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="!{!$Permission.Allow_This}">
        <apex:outputText>You do not have the necessary permissions to even see the button, let alone click it.</apex:outputText>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

It seems like $Permission only return true or null. If the custom permission is assigned to the User, you can render or not render based on $Permission. However if the custom permission is not assigned, neither pageBlock renders.

Is there a way to render a component only if a user does not have a particular Custom Permission assigned to them?

Comment: Did you try {!$Permission.Allow_This == true} and {!$Permission.Allow_This != true}. I think it should work...

Comment: @MaciekSimm `== true` and `!= true` is not necessary, and possibly even confusing in some contexts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. $Permission returns true or false, but never null. The problem was that your NOT operator was in the wrong place:

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!$Permission.Allow_This}">
        <apex:outputText>Click this button to do something</apex:outputText>
        <apex:commandButton value="Click Me!" action="{!clickButton}" />
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!!$Permission.Allow_This}">
        <apex:outputText>You do not have the necessary permissions to even see the button, let alone click it.</apex:outputText>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Everything you wish to evaluate must be between the `{!` and `}`, as everything outside of it would be treated literally. `!{!$Permission.Allow_This}` would render as the literal strings `!true` and `!false`. Visualforce treats any non-empty string that is not exactly false as a true value, and empty strings as a false value.

For readability, I prefer to write it as:

```
rendered="{!NOT($Permission.Allow_This)}"
```

Comment: It's not that they needed to have a space between the two `!`'s, it's that they had the first `!` on the wrong side of the `{`. `<apex:pageBlock rendered="!{!$Permission... ` is not valid, `<apex:pageBlock rendered="{!!$Permission....` is. But I agree with you that using the `NOT` operator clears up confusion.

Comment: @caleb.breckon Hmm... I think they fixed the merge syntax, though. `{!!` used to throw an error. I'll edit.